# SelectTagHelper not displaying selected item without explicit Id property in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I'm trying to create a dropdown list in MVC Core (2.2) for an Edit action.

I want to use an Enumerable of SelectListItems as my data source without adding an extra property to my ViewModel to hold the current selected value(s) as these are already stored in the SelectListItems.

I was using a customised SelectTagHelper (which removed the multiple attribute) which I thought might be the problem but I've tested with the standard SelectTagHelper and I can't find a way to capture the selected item(s) from the SelectListItems.

Is there a way to make the default SelectTagHelper work like this or do I need to extend the custom SelectTagHelper?

I've tried with a SelectList and an IEnumerable of SelectListItems and neither work the way I'd have thought would be possible.

When debugging, the items are returned correctly (with one having a selected value of true in the example below). I'm assuming there's something in the standard SelectTagHelper that prevents the selected item being parsed from the Items collection.

Code as follows:

Model (with SelectListItems):

```
public class TaskEditViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Week { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(int Id)
{
    var model = _repo.GetTaskEdit(Id);                       

    if (model != null)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    return NotFound();            
}
```

Repository:

```
public TaskEditViewModel GetTaskEdit(int Id)
{
    var query = _context.Task.Where(t => t.Id == Id);

    var model = query
                .ProjectTo<TaskEditViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                .Single();

    if (model != null)
    {
        var selected = query.First().ProjectId; //gets currently selected value as int
        var list = _context.Project.Select(x => new SelectListItem(x.Name, x.Id.ToString(), true ? x.Id == selected : false));

        model.ProjectId = list;

        return model;
    }

    return null;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ProjectId" class="control-label"></label>
        <selectOne asp-for="ProjectId" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.ProjectId"></selectOne>
        <span asp-validation-for="ProjectId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

Debugger:

[image: Debugger]

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="ProjectId">Project</label>
     <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a project." id="ProjectId" multiple="multiple" name="ProjectId">
       <option value="1">7 Day SAT</option>
       <option value="2">UEC</option>
     </select>
   <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ProjectId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @FatikhanGasimov I've been through the answer on that post already. The implication is that I need an extra property in my ViewModel just to hold the selected value which just seems to be a workaround rather than a fix.

Comment: That _is_ the right answer and not a workaround because after all, when you submit the form, you will actually need to send the data. And there, you want just send the selected ID and not a whole tree of possible options. So having a property that *just* contains the selected value is the right way for this.

Comment: @poke That would make sense if the whole tree of possible options wasn't being parsed to create the options list in the first place. I'm guessing I'm going to have to further customise the TagHelper to get what I want.

Comment: You need to separate server and client here. On the client, you only get rendered HTML and there you have a single `select` tag (which is an input element for a *single* value), and a list of `option` tags where each option has a single value. When you submit the form, the transferred data is only the single select tag and the selected option. That’s how this works. If you want to transfer more, you would have to have more form fields but that would be highly inefficient. Razor and tag helpers are only for *rendering* the HTML by the server, and after that the model is effectively thrown away.

Comment: @poke I think we're talking at cross purposes. I'm concerned with the rendering of the control into the browser. If I select a new item it gets returned as the form value once posted. I want one of my options to have a `selected` attribute when the select control is rendered.

Comment: Since you have `asp-for="ProjectId"`, the value of `ProjectId` will be used to match a value of the options to make it selected. So `ProjectId` there has to be a *value* of the items. If you don’t want that, then you cannot use `asp-for` there.

Comment: @poke This is NOT a duplicate of the previous question. I'm concerned with the selected value, not how to bind to a select list. I've written a custom TagHelper to solve my problem and, on the off-chance someone else has a similar use case, I'd like to post it as an answer.

Comment: Even if you have a working solution for your problem, you will have to update your question *first* to actually reflect what you are trying to do and to show that it’s a different question than the linked one. Just judging by your comments it still does not seem clear to me what you are actually doing and whether you are actually using the select *properly*.

Comment: @poke I've updated the question to better reflect what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to extend the custom TagHelper I was using to cover this as I wanted to provide a single TagHelper to cover both Create and Edit instances of the Select input.

This custom TagHelper removes the multiple attribute and creates an option list with the selected value taken from the SelectListItems passed via the model.

TagHelper:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("selectOne", Attributes = "asp-for")]
    public class SingleSelectTagHelper : SelectTagHelper
    {
        public SingleSelectTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
            : base (generator)
        {

        }       

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            base.Process(context, output);

            output.TagName = "select";           

            var index = output.Attributes.IndexOfName("multiple");
            output.Attributes.RemoveAt(index);

            output.PreContent.AppendHtml("<option value=\"\">Please select an option</option>");          

            output.PostContent.Reinitialize();

            foreach(var item in Items)
            {
                if(item.Selected)
                {
                    output.PostContent.AppendHtml($"<option selected='selected' value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>");
                }
                else
                {
                    output.PostContent.AppendHtml($"<option value=" + item.Value + ">" + item.Text + "</option>");
                }                
            }  
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ProjectId" class="control-label"></label>
        <selectOne asp-for="ProjectId" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.ProjectId"></selectOne>
        <span asp-validation-for="ProjectId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

Renders as:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="ProjectId">Project</label>
            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select a project." id="ProjectId" name="ProjectId">
                <option value="">Please select an option</option>
                <option value=1>Option 1</option>
                <option selected='selected' value=2>Option 2</option>
            </select>
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ProjectId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have already written in the comment, the select tag helper will use the `asp-for` element to bind to the view model. This means that the value of the model in the specified property is used to match a value of the available items of the tag helper to determine which items is currently selected. This process works regardless of what `SelectListItem` has its `Selected` property set to `true`.

That means, if you do not use `asp-for`, then you can totally have this work as you like:

```
// in the controller action
return View(new TaskEditViewModel
{
    ProjectId = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 1", Value = "value-1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 2", Value = "value-2", Selected = false },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 3", Value = "value-3" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 4", Value = "value-4" },
    },
});

// in the view
<select class="form-control" asp-items="Model.ProjectId"></select>
```

If you execute this, this will be the rendered output:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="value-1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="value-2">Item 2</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="value-3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="value-4">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

It’s only if you add the `asp-for` that this will stop working.

```
<select class="form-control" id="ProjectId" multiple="multiple" name="ProjectId">
    <option value="value-1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="value-2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="value-3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="value-4">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

This is because now, the form is rendering a form control for a property that is a list of something. So the tag helper assumes that it has to display a select allowing *multiple* selections. In addition, the logic will now try to match the `SelectListItem.Value` with the value of `Model.ProjectId` and only use that to determine if something is selected.

As noted in the comments, this is not how you would usually use the select tag helper here. Instead, you would have a separate property for the selected *value* and a separate property for the available items:

```
public class TaskEditViewModel
{
    // …
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableProjects { get; set; }
}

// in the controller
return View(new TaskEditViewModel
{
    ProjectId = "value-3",
    AvailableProjects = new List<SelectListItem>()
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 1", Value = "value-1" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 2", Value = "value-2" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 3", Value = "value-3" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Item 4", Value = "value-4" },
    },
});

// in the view
<select asp-for="ProjectId" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.AvailableProjects"></select>
```

Now, this is the HTML you will get:

```
<select class="form-control" id="ProjectId" name="ProjectId">
    <option value="value-1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="value-2">Item 2</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="value-3">Item 3</option>
    <option value="value-4">Item 4</option>
</select>
```

Note that item 3 is now implicitly selected even though its `SelectListItem` did not have the `Selected` property set. This is because the current value of `ProjectId` in the model happens to equal the `Value` of the `SelectListItem`. And that’s exactly the logic that this uses.

This approach has a huge benefit over using the `Selected` property in the `SelectListItem`: Now, it’s very clear what data is being sent when you submit the form. Since the value of the selected `option` is what is being sent, and the `name` of the `select` tag is the key that value is being used for, the submitting the form would effectively send `ProjectId=value-3` now.

And when that model is then bound as part of the POST action in the controller, that value can correctly be deserialized into the `ProjectId` property of your model:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(TaskEditViewModel model)
{
    var selectedProject = model.ProjectId; // "value-3"
    // …
}
```